# Convert HTML to RichText in Google App Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, richtext

I have to convert some HTML code to a Rich Text in order to assign it to a cell of a Google Spreadsheet App, and render it not as pure HTML, but as formatted text.

I am new on these stuffs, so I wish to have some suggestions from you.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think there are any built-in solutions except for creating a manual parser based on XmlService https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the rich text with HTML to the rich text into a cell of Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, [RichTextApp of a Google Apps Script library](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp) is used. I have created this library for managing the rich text between Google Spreadsheet, Google Document, and HTML.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

You can see the detail of this at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp#1-install-library).

#### 2. Sample script.

This sample script is from [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp#1-convert-html-data-to-rich-text-on-google-spreadsheet). This script uses Drive API. So [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function convertHTMLToRichText() {
  var html = '###'; // Please set your HTML data. Of course, you can retrieve this from a HTML file on Google Drive.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###").getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the Spreadsheet ID and sheet name.

  // Create Google Document by converting HTML to Google Document as a temporal file.
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, MimeType.HTML, "sample.html");
  var tempDocId = Drive.Files.insert(
    { title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS },
    blob
  ).id;

  // Put the value to a cell as the rich text using the method of "DocumentToSpreadsheet".

  var res = RichTextApp.DocumentToSpreadsheet({
    range: sheet.getRange("A1"),
    document: DocumentApp.openById(tempDocId),
  });
  console.log(res);

  // Remove the temporal file.
  DriveApp.getFileById(tempDocId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

- In this sample script, `html` of HTML data is converted to the rich text and put to a cell ("A1" of "Sheet1") of Google Spreadsheet as the rich text.

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your actual situation.

### Reference:

- [RichTextApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp)